# Cabal fails with proxy with authentication

Tags: cabal-install

This is a well-known bug that `cabal` can not handle proxies in format `http://user:password@host:port` format. On Haskell mailing list, someone suggested a patch to overcome this but that patch is now quite old.

It fails with following message

```
   Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
   Warning: invalid http proxy uri:
   "http://user:pass@host:80/"
   Warning: proxy uri must be http with a hostname
   Warning: ignoring http proxy, trying a direct connection
```

Does anyone know how to make cabal use my proxy settings? Any indirect method will also do such as proxy bypassing etc.

A [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/272168/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-for-cabal) is asked on superuser but it is not answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working with [polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/). My university uses `http-proxy` with authentication. In `/etc/polipo/config` you need to add these lines

```
parentProxy = "proxy.server.com:80"
parentAuthCredentials = "myusername:mypassword"
```

And export `http_proxy=http://localhost:8123"`. And it worked like a charm.

Comment: i tried using polipo in any browser, it works fine for http links, but opening https links asks for authentication. please help

Comment: I havn't tried it with https. Did u try exporting https_proxy to http://localhost:8123? If yes, then I am out of ideas.

Comment: i tried using all manual proxy settings of firefox to 127.0.0.1:8123, but in vain. It asks for authentication, with https browsing like gmail.com or github.com. Please see if it could work the same as http. Thanks in advance. I also have posted this question in forums: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92971/https-authentication-problem-polipo

Comment: Shooting in dark : Are u running pilipo as root? `sudo service polipo restart` should do it. And check if polipo is running successfully. I really cant reproduce it now for I am no longer on my campus where I was behind proxy.

Comment: I have been doing the whole thing as root, in fact there has also been issues before: http://www.mail-archive.com/polipo-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00859.html