# cabal can't use http proxy

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

My Linux(redhat6) server has to use http proxy to connect to outside world. While it works for other things like wget, it doesn't work for cabal.

```
cabal update -v3
```

shows errors like this:

> 407 - proxy authentication required cabal: Failed to download
>   http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz :
>   ErrorMisc "Unsucessful HTTP code: 407"

I tried to change http_proxy environment variable to format like http:// user: passwd at proxy:port, but it doesn't work either.

The same problem has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310218/cabal-fails-with-proxy-with-authentication)

But I'm not allowed use a proxy server like polipo, is there any other way to make cabal work behind a proxy?

Comment: How about using `cntlm` ? It takes care of authentication.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: redhat6, sorry forgot to say, added in my question. I just got cntlm up and running, but cabal still give the same error.

Comment: @swang Did you set up new `http_proxy` and other environmental variable after setting up `cntlm` ?

Comment: ah.....i see, i need to redirect http_proxy to talk to cntlm, it works now, thanks so much!! how do i accept your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) to talk to proxy. It will handle authentication issues. After configuring and installing `cntlm`, set up the new environmental variable by modifying `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` etc.

Your `cabal` command should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

some detailed procedure here:

1. Download cntlm from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/)
   It's a c program with no other dependencies so very easy to make, just follow the instructions in the downloaded package.
2. After installing cntlm, follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181637/how-to-fill-proxy-information-in-cntlm-config-file) from Colonel Panic. Obviously on linux you need to change cntlm.exe to ./cntlm, I named the configure file cntlm.conf
3. The default listen port for cntlm is 3124, if you can't use that port, change it to something else like 53124, then add this to your cntlm.conf or cntlm.ini file:

   ```
   Listen              127.0.0.1:53124
   ```
4. Start cntlm in the background:

   ```
   ./cntlm -c cntlm.conf
   ```
5. Change your http_proxy environment variable to talk to the cntlm process rather than the real proxy.

   ```
   export http_proxy=http:// 127.0.0.1:53124
   ```

That's it, cabal will work as good as ever.

Comment: `wget` respects the environmental variable `http_proxy` and others. So it should work if you set up the proper environment variables.

Comment: I set http_proxy properly but not https_proxy, maybe I messed up somewhere, will have another look when i get back to the office.

Comment: You may also want to check up the doc of wget. It seems to have options for setting up proxy. In my office, I work under proxy and `wget` has no problems with cntlm once I set up the environmental variables properly. :)

Comment: yes you are right, don't know why it didn't work the first time, but it definitely works now, edited my own answer

Answer (score -1):

You can also setup the http_proxy directly in the system setting:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@hostname:port
```