# cabal: Failed to download, ErrorMisc "Error HTTP code: 407"

Tags: windows, haskell

Windows 7 x64 SP1 Russian, Virtual machine (VMware) are located on server.

I installed the Haskell from [official site](http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) yesterday. But I have a problem when I start the command: `cabal update`. Error message:

> C:\Users\admin>cabal update Downloading the latest package list from
>   hackage.haskell.org cabal: Failed to download
>   http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz :
>   ErrorMisc "Error HTTP code: 407"

Internet access is exists. The command ran under admin profile. How can I to correct this issue?

P.S. When I did the same on my home notebook - all worked fine, without this message.

Answer (score 1):

Http status code 407 means "Proxy authentication required". So it seems to be local issue with proxy configuration.

See also: [cabal can't use http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137795/cabal-cant-use-http-proxy)

Add: `cabal` [uses](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/5c70361b362e41b3c13d48b58b46224d42f401dc/cabal-install/Distribution/Client/HttpUtils.hs#L55) `fetchProxy` from `HTTP` package, it [should](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/Network-HTTP-Proxy.html#v:fetchProxy) read IE proxy config.
I don't use windows, so I have no idea what can be wrong. You can try to call `fetchProxy` manually and see what it returns. If it returns correct value, then open issue on `cabal` tracker. Otherwise, open issue in `HTTP` package tracker.

Comment: Is the `cabal` don't read the settings of connecting from the Internet Explorer?

Comment: How can I do authentication for this case? The `cabal` program has not asked the login and password for the proxy authentication.

Comment: I updated the answer with more details about proxy. But I'm not even sure `cabal` supports proxy authentication at all...

Comment: cabal supports proxy authentication, but the best way to do so is to set your env variables in the shell.